# Possible to bind multiple variables to a tkinter messagebox

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I am looking to bind multiple variables into a tkinter messagebox. Is this possible? I do have some sample code that I put together plus it's error code.

```
    lines = ['Principal Amount: %s', 'Rate: %s', 'Time: %s years.', 'Compounded: %s times a year.'] % (principal, rate, time, compound)
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Compound Interest Result:', "\n".join(lines))
```

And it returns this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/---/Documents/test.py", line 16, in compoundInterest
    lines = ['Principal Amount: %s', 'Rate: %s', 'Time: %s years.', 'Compounded: %s times a year.'] % (principal, rate, time, compound)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'tuple'
```

Unfortunately through research I have not been able to find anything that shows how to correctly bind variables to messageboxes so I am unaware about it's mere possibility. If there is another way I am open to hear it!

(Be aware I am new to Python and tkinter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the messagebox but with your definition of *lines* as mentioned in the error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'tuple'
```

This works:

```
tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Compound Interest Result:', "\n".join(["test1","test2","test3"]))
```

To create *lines* you can for example do:

```
sList=['Principal Amount: {}', 'Rate: {}', 'Time: {} years.', 'Compounded: {} times a year.']
valueList=['test1', 'test2','test3','test4']
lines = [s.format(value) for s,value in zip(sList,valueList)]
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Worked like a charm!